# Form post to secure route Forbidden

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a route which requires authentication and authorization. Currently I have achieved this using the users [api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) in python.

This is my HTML form

```
<form action="/xxxx/xxxx/Add-Article" id="form-Save-Article" method=post>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtArticleTitle">Article Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="ArticleTitle" class="form-control" id="txtArticleTitle" placeholder="Article Title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtArticleAuthor">Article Author</label>
            <input type="text" name="ArticleAuthor" class="form-control" id="txtArticleAuthor" placeholder="Article Author">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtArticleContent">Article Content</label>
            <input type="text" name="ArticleContent" class="form-control" id="txtArticleContent"
                   placeholder="Article Content">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Add New Article
        </button>
    </form>
```

And this is the route which handles it.

```
@admin_articles_routes.route('/xxxx/xxxx/Add-Article', methods=['GET','POST'])
@cross_domain(origin="*")
@authenticate_admin
def add_articles():
    af = ArticleFactory()
    article_title = request.args['ArticleTitle']
    article_author = request.args['ArticleAuthor']
    article_content = request.args['ArticleContent']
    article = af.get_new_article()
    article.title = article_title
    article.author = article_author
    article.content = article_content
    af.add_article(article)
    return redirect('/xxxx/Articles')
```

When I fill the form and submit it I get the following error with 403 status code.

[image]

Even if I remove the cross_domain decorator, it still gives me 403 status.

I have tried to remove the following line from the HTML, however i still get the 403.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to [same-origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

The following [article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket) from Google Cloud Platform explains it very clearly.

I ended up running the following command on cloud storage bucket to fix the issue.

```
gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://example
```